# Slow file transfer rate in wireless lan on from/to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lan

I got one win 7 machine one route and one ubuntu machine, the router got storage slots.
tranfers from ubuntu to router are fast(3MBps), but anyt tranfer related to windows machine is slow(256KBps)

why?

Comment: Are the different wifi adaptors using different protocols?

Comment: @HaydnWVN: how can I know?